# Error desconocido en Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un error que no logro entender porque sucede cuando ejecuto el runserver en django. Es el siguiente:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/code/historical/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .settings import (
  File "/code/historical/models/settings.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .measurements import Measurement
  File "/code/historical/models/measurements.py", line 9, in <module>
    from comms.structs import DataStruct
  File "/code/comms/structs.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .structs_old import *
  File "/code/comms/structs_old.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .structs_blocks_old import *
  File "/code/comms/structs_blocks_old.py", line 31, in <module>
    class PIDControllerParams(MBusSerializable):
  File "/code/comms/structs_blocks_old.py", line 32, in PIDControllerParams
    pCoefficient: i16 = EEPROM.new(default=0, metadata={'description': _('Ganancia proporcional')})
  File "/code/comms/mbus_types.py", line 27, in new
    return EEPROM(default, default_factory, init, repr, hash, compare, metadata)
TypeError: Field.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'kw_only'
```

He revisado base de datos y en principio no hay ningún problema, conecta bien, pero tampoco me guarda ninguna tabla, no se si van por ahí los tiros.
Este error a ocurrido sin modificar nada. Antes funcionaba perfectamente. El despliegue se hace con docker. Si despliego manualmente tampoco funciona.

¿Alguna idea de porque?

Gracias!

Comment: No pegues imágenes en las que deba leerse el texto. En muchos dispositivos la lectura es muy difícil. Copia el texto de la excepción y pégalo como texto (delimitado por ``` para que salga correctamente formateado).

Comment: Corregido. Gracias!

Comment: Es difícil señalar el problema sin ver el código. A la vista del error parece que, o bien olvidaste declarar el parámetro `self` en algún método de alguna clase (concretamente en un `__init__()`) o bien olvidaste pasarle un primer parámetro posicional obligatorio, o bien estás usando una clase en un lugar donde deberías estar usando una instancia de una clase.

Comment: Problema solucionado. Resulta que he estado usando siempre la ultima version de python. Y con la nueva version (3.10) hay algo que no funciona bien.